# RAD 7: Debug GWT based Portlets

Tags: debugging, gwt, plugins, rad, websphere-portal

I have a Portlet which is based on GWT and it must be deployed on Websphere Portal Server.
For development purposes, I need to have debugging working inside RAD (with embedded Portal Server).
So, i installed RAD 7.5.4 with Portal Server 6.1.
I made all configuration on both Server and RAD to work with debugginh.
But when i make breakpoints on (GWT) JAVA files, its not working .
JSP and normal Java works with debugging but only GWT based projects are not working.

Is there any GWT plugin available for RAD to make debugging possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is [compiled](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html) into Javascript so it is possible that the Java code you are expecting to debug has been compiled and hence not running on the Portal Server.  You should be able to debug your [GWT Server side components](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) using the debugger in RAD.